# Have a new Dell Inspiron 15 with Ubuntu 14.14LTS but have massive technical problems

Tags: inspiron, data-corruption

I've just bought a new Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series Laptop with Ubuntu 14.14LTS pre-installed but after a failed attempt at upgrading to Ubuntu v15.10 "Wily Warewolf", I had to do a factory reset which also failed and seems to have deleted the restore partition so my system now has no sound, internet or mouse functionality :(. I've found somewhere local that can repair it but would rather do it myself if possible so does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this without having to pay someone to do it for me?

Also note that I rang Dell immediately after this problem occurred but was fobbed off with excuses as to why they wouldn't help me and was told that my warranty wouldn't cover this problem since it was software related and not an hardware issue :(. I'm completely new to Linux so am completely out of my depth with these issues.

Comment: I know with a brand new pc one always wants to upgrade to the latest and greatest. In this case I strongly suggest sticking with 14.04.4 as suggested by @Android Dev since that realease will remain supported until 2019 which gives you plenty chance to learn the ins and outs of Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't panic

2) Download the 14.04 ISO from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

3) Burn it to a blank DVD or to a USB stick.

4) Boot the computer from media you just created.

5) Install it using the option to wipe the HDD.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work as my system just boots to a safe mode screen and won't go any further without spitting out an "Invalid Signature" error, plus I don't get any options to reinstall Linux :(. I tried creating a Live USB Drive so I could boot from that but the same thing happens and now I can't even get to the Desktop :(.

Comment: UPDATE: I have found a boot option in the Bios menu that I had previously missed and am now reinstalling Ubuntu :).

Comment: UPDATE 2: All fixed, I've spent the last 40 odd mins playing around with the system and everything seems to be in order so thank you for the help :).